# How to pass all row data in eloquent and get with jquery

Tags: jquery, mysql, ajax, laravel, eloquent

I have a case study here. i want get row when option selected with jquery and set value textfield where id from option selected, and in my case iam confused get all row from eloquent with jquery ,please help me

controller

```
 public function getID($id)
{
    $data = TunjanganPenggajianModel::where('nip',$id)->get();
    echo json_encode($data);

}
```

jquery

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
        table = $('#example').DataTable({
            "ajax": "<?php echo url('/data_tunjangan') ?>"
        });

        $('#nama').on('change', function () {
            var optionText = $("#nama option:selected").val();
            $.ajax({
                url: "<?php echo url('/'); ?>" + "/getidtunjangan/" + optionText,
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "JSON",
                success: function (data) {
                    $('[name="jabatan"]').val(data.jabatan);
                    $('[name="tunjangan_jabatan"]').val(data.jenis_tunjangan);
                    $('[name="tunjangan_beras"]').val(data.jenis_tunjangan);
                },
                error: function (request, status, error) {
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

my Table View

```
ID      nama   jabatan    gaji_Pokok   jenis_tunjangan   besar_tunjangan

10010   Muhammad Hayyi  Pimpinan    1425000 jabatan pimpinan    140000

10010   Muhammad Hayyi  Pimpinan    1425000 kesehatan pimpinan  150000

10010   Muhammad Hayyi  Pimpinan    1425000 beras pimpinan  250000

10010   Muhammad Hayyi  Pimpinan    1425000 Tunjangan Prestasi pimpinan 2425000

10010   Muhammad Hayyi  Pimpinan    1425000 Tunjangan Sirkulasi pimpinan    1711000

10010   Muhammad Hayyi  Pimpinan    1425000 Tunjangan Kepulangan pimpinan   290000

10010   Muhammad Hayyi  Pimpinan    1425000 Tunjangan DO pimpinan   4600000
```

Comment: Maybe you need something like [this example](https://makitweb.com/fetch-records-from-mysql-with-jquery-ajax-laravel/).

`$.ajax({
         url: '/url',
         type: 'get',
         dataType: 'json',
         success: function(data){

             for(var i=0; i<len; i++){
                    $('[name="jabatan"]').val(data.jabatan);
                    $('[name="tunjangan_jabatan"]').val(data.jenis_tunjangan);
                    $('[name="tunjangan_beras"]').val(data.jenis_tunjangan);
             }
        })`

Comment: Are u trying to get all the value from the controller and set the value in text field?

Comment: @CHARITRASHRESTHA Yes

Answer (score 1):

You should use return instead of echo

```
 public function getID($id)
{
    $data = TunjanganPenggajianModel::where('nip',$id)->get();
    return $data;

}
```

Comment: if i use this i just got first row i want get all row when option selected is same in view

Comment: @AndrewLee change first to get

Answer (score 0):

Then why are you using javascript? Simply pass the data to the input text filed value attribute. IF you really need Ajax request then get the html view with input value along with data in it and add the whole section in the HTML.
For that change.

```
dataType: "JSON",
```

to

```
dataType: "HTML",
```